# Sorting a JSON by value of a dynamic name property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I've been trying to do an online coding excericise, the excercise look like this :

> A json array A has a random number objects that contains a key and a
>   double value. The array A may have up to 10000 objects. Ex: A = [{"a":
>   2.0},{"a": 2.7},{"c": 2.0},{"b": 5.1},{"d": 2.9},{"c": 2.0},{"f": 2.2},{"h": 2.1}]
>
> Another array B has a random set of sum operations executed with the
>   keys. The value of those keys can be found in A. If the key is not
>   presented in A, so its value is zero. Ex: B = ["a+b","b+d+f","k+z"]
>
> Your job is to combine the arrays B and A, providing an array C that
>   contains the results of the sum operations of B. The resulting array
>   must be sorted in a descending order.  Combining the examples above,
>   the resulting array would be: Ex: C = [ {"b+d+f": 10.2}, {"a+b": 9.8},
>   {"k+z": 0} ]

The code looks like this (please let me know if there is any better implementation whit a smaller O())

```js
var a = [{"a": 2.0},{"a": 2.7},{"c": 2.0},{"b": 5.1},{"d": 2.9},{"c": 2.0},{"f": 2.2},{"h": 2.1}]
var b = ["a+b","b+d+f","k+z"];
var c = [];

function sumArrays(){ 
 for (var sum in b){
  var keysToSum = b[sum].split("+");
  var sumatory = 0;
  for(var key in keysToSum){   
   for(var number in a){
    if(a[number].hasOwnProperty(keysToSum[key])){
     sumatory += a[number][keysToSum[key]];
    }
   }
  }

  c.push(JSON.parse("{\"" + b[sum] + "\":" + sumatory + "}"));
 }

 //c.sort(function(a,b){
 // return a.value - b.value;
 //});
}
```

I can't get the array C sorted, because the property name changes. Any ideas?

Thanks !

Comment: quick fix something like `a[Object.keys(a)[0]] -b[Object.keys(b)[0]]`

Comment: do you know that in `A` array you have an objects with duplicated property name, i mean `{"a": 2.0},{"a": 2.7}` and others? what value should be used in this case?

Comment: i suggest not use [for..in loop with array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Very intresting case, Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need the first value of an object:

```
function firstValue(obj){
   for(var prop in obj){
      return obj[prop];
   }
}
```

then use it for sort

```
a.sort(function(a,b){ return firstValue(a)-firstValue(b)})
```